# check if text “begin with” substring in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I check if a text “begin with” substring in Actionscript 3 ??

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an indexOf method: [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf%28%29).

It returns the **first** index of where the given string appears in the string that is searched. If this is not equal to `0`, it doesn't start with the string. You can make the following function yourself:

```
function startsWith(haystack:String, needle:String):boolean {
    return haystack.indexOf(needle) == 0;
}
```